Is A Piano Arrangement For A Song Sufficient For Understanding Its Harmony?
I previously made full scores of songs. However, this proved very time consuming. I don't want a lead sheet since that isn't detailed enough, so I thought making a piano arrangement would give me a good understanding of a song's harmony and why I like it.

It would help to know something of why you think or imagine it wouldn't be sufficient. Otherwise, the answer seems obvious.

Well, I lose some harmonic details by arranging for piano no? If the song has more than 2 voices, I have to get rid of some voices to fit it into the piano.

Piano can handle more than two voices. Bach, for example, wrote for as many as six.

Sorry I meant different melodies, each with their own rhythms. Is that possible on piano for 6 voices?

Yes. That's the kind of thing Bach wrote. Plus, for a harmonic study, you generally only need two or three, sometimes four.

Perhaps an example from a full score whose harmony you think might be lost in transcribing for the piano would help to illustrate this question.  The abstract discussion seems not to be terribly fruitful.

What types and musical styles of songs? Originals? Transcriptions? Sorry, way too vague.

there are a lot of red hearings to discuss here, but I feel like a highly answerable version of this question would be: “I want to do a harmonic analysis of a work that’s originally meant for ensemble. Is a piano arrangement a helpful place to start?“ If that’s the core of your question, I think I’ll answer focusing on it, and I encourage you to edit to emphasize that part.

Piano reductions of symphonies are common, so in general I would expect you could do piano arrangements of your songs. Post some examples that concern you from your scores. It's probably a matter of finding solutions for your particular songs.

The title is missing the word ‘making’ from the question, which seems to affect the meaning.  (Perhaps the exercise of creating an arrangement will give you insights into harmony, even if the resulting arrangement doesn't capture them?  Conversely, would obtaining an arrangement that someone else created necessarily give you the insights you want?)

The core of this question seems to be, "If I want to do harmonic analysis of a work that isn't written for piano, do I need a piano arrangement first?" The answer is certainly not, but it might help save some time... sometimes.
Some of the steps in analysis are 1) to figure out what's being played, 2) to figure out how to describe it, and 3) to figure out what it all means. Step 1 is easy if there is original sheet music for the work; for instance, to analyze a symphony, you could start with the score. If you're analyzing a rock song that the musicians never wrote down, then you also need the step of transcribing the music into writing. But it's hard (unless you're used to it) to look at a large score, like for a symphony, and say "Oh look, there's a I chord, there's a vi, there's a modulation." To analyze the harmony first we identify the chords. If the piece is very complex, this is where it might help to have a simplified version, like a piano arrangement. It makes it easier to spot the chords on only two staves. If the original has transposing instruments like saxophones or trumpets, it takes care of the transposition for us. If you're making this piano reduction yourself, the act of simply creating it might speed you through the early stages of noticing details in the music and explaining them.
But it's dangerous. If you're not creating an arrangement but looking for one, it's easy to find poor arrangements created by amateurs that might contain errors or be hard to read. And even with skilled arrangements, there's no guarantee of how closely the arrangement matches the original. When "arranging" a work for a new instrument, you get the most pleasing result if you make it fit that instrument's sound and style, and that could mean radically reinterpreting it. I used the word "piano reduction" just now; that could be a better way of talking about something that is faithful and useful, just simpler than the original.
You mentioned "I don't want a lead sheet since that isn't detailed enough." I would challenge that. This second step in analysis, assuming that we already have notated music, is about simplification. It means looking at those notes and asking what chords they represent. An accurate lead sheet can be a huge shortcut here since it names the chords. We can skip from "What is this stack of dots," past "Oh, it's a G7," and straight to "But wait, what is it doing in the key of F? How do we explain its function?" Lead sheet comes with the same warnings that it's even more prone to amateurish guesswork and might not represent the original accurately, but if you can find an accurate version it could help in the simplification step.
Let's also address the question of why you're doing this analysis. You say you want "a good understanding of a song's harmony." There are many ways of analyzing a song; harmonic analysis is one. But to "understand" the song, even to "understand the harmony," could mean using that data for various purposes. This is the third step, figuring out "what it all means." Think of it as scientific inquiry: If I say "I want to understand those mountains," then my approach and conclusions will depend on what kind of scientist I am. A geologist will take rock samples and talk about how the mountains were formed; a biologist will study its plants and animals and talk about their interactions; a sociologist will study its human communities and their ways of life. All three can put their findings together to form an "understanding of those mountains" (perhaps together with even more disciplines). We can use our harmonic analysis to say things about how the song uses its keys or moves between them, how it organizes its sections, or even the variety or nature of the chords it chooses. And harmonic analysis is only one kind of analysis.
You say your goal is to figure out "why you like it." It's not a safe assumption that you like the song primarily because of its harmonic motion. I greatly enjoy some songs that have nothing more than I, IV, and V, but find others with the same chords boring. Consider that your enjoyment of the song might depend on its melody, its rhythms, its instrumentation, the textures of how those instruments are used, its phrasal structure, its tempo, its dynamics, or more. All those things can be "analyzed" in varying ways, like the scientists gathering rock samples, animal droppings, and human interviews.
This is another way an arrangement of the song might be useful. If it does alter the song, you might notice things that it changed that you miss, or things that it keeps the same that maintain your enjoyment. If available, try exploring other artists' reinterpretation of the same work in covers, remixes, etc.

One thing I don't see here is that the full score (transposed) could lead to more analysis errors when reading transposing instruments and alto or tenor clef, while a piano reduction only requires reading the notes.

@ToddWilcox - I get your point, but reading transposing instruments or reading in alto or tenor clef is also just reading the notes...
